# Input Box method to inputting date within a dynamic Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I currently run a very simple piece of vba code which runs a simple `if` formula that checks whether the sales I made are within a certain date. like below...

```
sub date
lastrow1 = Sheets("Tracker").cells.Find("*", cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
        Sheets(1).Activate
        With Sheets(1)
        .Range("BG2:BG" & lastrow1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-18]>DATE(2020,1,1),""Yes"",""No"")"
        End With
end sub
```

This works fine, but as its rather tedious to go back into the code and amend the date within the parenthesis (e.g in this case (20,1,1)) every time I want to amend the date, I want to create a little input box that will allow me to update the date automatically. I cant however seem to get it to work, could anyone help get me on the right path. thanks.

```
sub dateinput
lastrow1 = Sheets("Tracker").cells.Find("*", cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

Dim InputDate As String, dte As Date
Sheets(1).Activate
InputDate = Application.InputBox("Format yyyy,m,dd", Title:="Please Select Date", Type:=2)
If IsDate(InputDate) Then
Range("BG2:BG" & lastrow1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-18]>Date(InputDate),""Yes"",""No"")"
Else
MsgBox ("Date not valid")
End If
With Sheets(1)
.Range("BG2:BG" & lastrow1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-18]>DATE(2020,1,1),""Yes"",""No"")"
End With
end sub
```

Comment: You can use a cell with data validation to control the input and then use it in your formula as a constant reference.

Comment: yes i understand that way, Can it be done with an input box? its a cleaner way of doing it

Comment: To me putting a cell reference in a formula is much cleaner than `InputBox` which you have noticed by now is going to be more messy. If you want to control this then you need to create a userform with date control.

Comment: the tracker i use is updated constantly amongst my employees - im just not a big fan of the cell reference idea. i wouldn't know how to make the userform @shrivallabha.redij

Comment: If you google then [example 1](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/insert-calendar-clicking-cell-excel-29766.html), [example 2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-date-picker-afa0aea0-d4e3-4424-8e0a-c08f65928f84) etc will come up.